# cannot find entry file index.js in any of the roots

Tags: android, react-native

I have a react native project and when i run "react-native run-android" , get this error:

> cannot find entry file index.js in any of the root

version of react-native is 0.52.3

Comment: Your Android application must be looking for an index.js file and your react native code probably doesn't have it. Can you confirm your index.js file exists?

Comment: @NemiShah yes, it does

Comment: Did this happen immediately after creating the react native application? Or did you make some changes and if you did what changes did you make? Don't mean to pry just need more information

Comment: @NemiShah when i run app on mobile, getting this error

Answer (score 1):

If you are using windows 10 downgrade your react version, cause 0.52.3 not work and it have many bugs.

```
npm install react-native@0.43.8
```

Comment: i'm using ubuntu 18.04